# First page of the Diary - Quote

Tags: quotes

am gifting some one a diary I want to write something meaningful in the first page of it.

All I could come up with is...

**In the most ammaaazing journey that you are yet to embark upon, Called Life!**

**Record all your beautiful memories.. so that one day you'll have something sensational to read**

what I meant is that the person will have an amazing life(in future)

Please help me improve this.. I am not even sure if this conveys what I mean. Please suggest if you can think of anything better than this to write on a first page of the Diary.

If you haven't figured it out already, English is not my first language. Please help.

Comment: You might consider writing a meaningful quote in your native language and then explaining it when you give the gift.

Comment: I think the second sentence about recording your memories is fine. The first one is oddly punctuated and doesn't entirely make sense to me. If you opt for that one I would suggest changing it to "You have embarked upon the most amazing journey. It's called life." (It's incorrect to say that the recipient has *yet* to embark on life, unless they are a newborn baby!) All in all, though, I think that Kit Z. Fox's suggestion is best. Everyone is most eloquent in their own language, and when the recipient sees the inscription in your language they will be reminded of you.

Comment: @lostinfrance thanks that's very helpful.. What I wanted to convey in first sentence is that this person has an amazing life.. How would I do that?!

Comment: If you gave the diary to me, I would prefer to not have *your* words in *my* diary. It would keep me from wanting to use it.

Comment: I'm afraid asking what to write is off-topic here. Closed, but please feel free to edit if you have a question that's more on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like:

May you treasure memories past and look ahead to the bright promise of tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could write some nice sentiments along the bottom of pages in the middle of the  book and not say anything so it's a surprise when they find them